# Trying to create a 12 month ahead one step forecast in R

Tags: r, forecasting

Trying to create this one-step-ahead forecast but am fairly inexperienced with R and am running into issues. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I was able to make a 6 month one step with this code:

```
etsfit <- ets(training)
one.step.e <- ts(vector(length=6), frequency=12, start=c(2020, 9))
jj <- 1
for (i in c(9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2)) {
  if(i==1) {j=2021} else {j=2020} 
  zz<-forecast(etsfit, h=1) 
  one.step.e[jj]<-zz$mean
  y.2<-window(data, end=c(j,i)) 
  etsfit<-ets(y.2,model = "MMM")
  jj<-jj+1
}
```

but when I try to use it for a 12 month one step I'm running into issues
here's what I have for the 12 month:

```
etsfit <- ets(training)
one.step.e <- ts(vector(length=12), frequency=12, start=c(2021, 3))
jj<-1
for (i in c(3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 1, 2)) {
  if(i==1) {j=2022} else {j=2021} 
  zz<-forecast(etsfit, h=1) 
  one.step.e[jj]<-zz$mean
  y.2<-window(data,end=c(j,i)) 
  etsfit<-ets(y.2,model = "MMM")
  }
one.step.e
```

It gives me this output

```
          Jan      Feb      Mar      Apr      May      Jun      Jul      Aug      Sep      Oct      Nov
2021                   12919246 14083081 14083081 14083081 14083081 14083081 14083081 14083081 14083081
2022 14083081 14083081
```

Comment: can you share your data so that we can reproduce `training` ?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16e_hHOheA8KkqLQ8JywdN5qWhCShWAGojFLF9NaZk9U/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I used up until august 2020 for the initial training set but wanted to use the whole the whole data set for the 12 month forecast